# avoid middle whitespace in UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, whitespace

I am new to Iphone development. I have tried the following code, but it does not work with middle whitespace in `UITEXTFIELD`.

```
NSString *t1 = [txt.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

How can I avoid middle whitespace?

Comment: check this tutorial very nice ... http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2011/01/allowing-only-characters-and-numbers-in.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this code may this use full.

```
NSString *t1=[txt.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *t1= [txt.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i tried, but it only replacing the spaces. if the user leaves two whitespace again we should change the code. any other idea?

Comment: check this tutorial very nice ... http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2011/01/allowing-only-characters-and-numbers-in.html

Comment: Thanks jeeva, somewhat better